# Trying to set the max_gram and min_gram in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, n-gram, elasticsearch-analyzers

Im trying to deploy a Ruby on Rails app on a Ubuntu 16.04 EC2 server but is giving a error about the difference between max_gram and min_gram on Elasticsearch, i don't have any experience with Elasticsearch yet so im totally lost here and i need some guidance to do this and learn how to set it to avoid this problems in the future.

The first time i did the deploy there was a error refusing the connection to localhost:9200 so i had to check if the service was running and even check the firewall and at the end i had to do a clean install and configure everything on elasticsearch.yml and now is running and working but when i try to deploy again is giving me a error, did a lot of search on internet there is a lot of documentation but i still don't get where to set these values.

This is the error im getting on the log:

```
-----> Migrating database...
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

[400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The difference between max_gram and min_gram in NGram Tokenizer must be less than or equal to: [1] but was [49]. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_ngram_diff] index level setting."}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The difference between max_gram and min_gram in NGram Tokenizer must be less than or equal to: [1] but was [49]. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_ngram_diff] index level setting."},"status":400}
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-6.0.2/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:205:in `__raise_transport_error'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-6.0.2/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:323:in `perform_request'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-6.0.2/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-6.0.2/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:131:in `perform_request'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-api-6.0.2/lib/elasticsearch/api/namespace/common.rb:21:in `perform_request'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-api-6.0.2/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/indices/create.rb:86:in `create'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/searchkick-3.0.2/lib/searchkick/index.rb:16:in `create'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/searchkick-3.0.2/lib/searchkick/index.rb:203:in `create_index'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/searchkick-3.0.2/lib/searchkick/index.rb:270:in `reindex_scope'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/searchkick-3.0.2/lib/searchkick/index.rb:196:in `reindex'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/searchkick-3.0.2/lib/searchkick/model.rb:59:in `searchkick_reindex'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/releases/20190807135404/db/migrate/20180405153226_validated_true.rb:4:in `change'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:789:in `exec_migration'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:773:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:772:in `block in migrate'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in `with_connection'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:771:in `migrate'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:951:in `migrate'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1232:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1302:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1231:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1203:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1202:in `each'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1202:in `migrate_without_lock'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1150:in `block in migrate'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1319:in `with_advisory_lock'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1150:in `migrate'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1006:in `up'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/migration.rb:984:in `migrate'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:163:in `migrate'
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in `block (2 levels) in '
/home/deploy/catalogindustry/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `
```

There is no index files on elasticsearch and there is nothing about this setting on the default template

Comment: Can you tell which app this is? Are you using the [elasticsearch-ruby](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby) client? Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: Yes, elasticsearch-ruby is added on the gemfile and installed, using the current version of ES or 7.3

Comment: Updated the log with more lines and the ruby app is a catalog website

Comment: If you're using ES 7.3, you need to make sure to use the gem version 7.x as well

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have faced a similar issue and below error message is clearly explaining the issue.

> [400]
>   {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The
>   difference between max_gram and min_gram in NGram Tokenizer must be
>   less than or equal to: [1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html#_configuration_16) but was [49]. This limit can be set by
>   changing the [index.max_ngram_diff] index level
>   setting."}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The
>   difference between max_gram and min_gram in NGram Tokenizer must be
>   less than or equal to: [1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html#_configuration_16) but was [49]. This limit can be set by
>   changing the [index.max_ngram_diff] index level
>   setting."},"status":400}

Basically, by Default, the difference between max_gram and min_gram in NGram Tokenizer can't be more than 1 and if you want you to change this, then in your index settings you need to change it by adding below setting.

```
"max_ngram_diff" : "50" --> you can mention this number accoding to your requirement.
```

Below is my index settings, where you can see I have a difference of `47` in my `max_gram` and `min_gram` hence set `max_ngram_diff` to `50`.

```
{ 
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "prefix": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercaseFilter"
                        ],
                        "tokenizer": "edgeNGramTokenizer"
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer": {
                    "edgeNGramTokenizer": {
                        "token_chars": [
                            "letter",
                            "digit"
                        ],
                        "min_gram": "1",
                        "type": "edgeNGram",
                        "max_gram": "40"
                    },
                    "loginNGram": {
                        "type": "nGram",
                        "min_gram": "3",
                        "max_gram": "50"
                    }
                }
            },
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "number_of_replicas": "0",
            "max_ngram_diff" : "50"
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Adding an [official](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html#_configuration_16) Elastic documentation, which explains that default length of max_gram is 2 and min_gram is 1, hence default difference between these can't be more than 1, hence the exception. And then snippet from the same doc

> The index level setting index.max_ngram_diff controls the maximum
>   allowed difference between max_gram and min_gram.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, but when i search for any index with this command:

`curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty"`

I get as response: `health status index uuid pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size`
Meaning there is no index file created, so from where come the error then?

Comment: yeah, due to this error, the index wasn't created, hence you need to create the index again with the setting `max_ngram_diff`.

Comment: @CesarRodriguez , any luck ?

Comment: Hi Amit sorry for the delay but i was on a travel, i din't found the solution for this issue so i ended up making a new instance and installing everything from scratch and i was able to deploy, but you was right about the file being created with that setting and for some reason on a new instance it was created properly this time so now the website is up and running with no issues

Answer (score 5):

One can also use an index template to apply the setting automatically to all new indices:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_index_template/template_1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "index_patterns": [
      "*"
  ],
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
         "max_ngram_diff": 50
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

The template will not be deleted by removing every index, but has to be removed manually:

```
curl -X DELETE "localhost:9200/_index_template/template_1
```