# Ruby On Rails Searchkick gem error: "The difference between max_gram and min_gram in NGram Tokenizer must be less than or equal to: [1]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

So I want to use the searchkick gem in my RoR app. I'm just following the readme on the github page.

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick

But when I run `Product.reindex` It throws the following error:

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The difference between max_gram and min_gram in NGram Tokenizer must be less than or equal to: [1] but was [49]. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_ngram_diff] index level setting."}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The difference between max_gram and min_gram in NGram Tokenizer must be less than or equal to: [1] but was [49]. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_ngram_diff] index level setting."},"status":400}
    from /home/Hendrik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.6/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:132:in `__raise_transport_error'
    from /home/Hendrik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.6/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:224:in `perform_request'
    from /home/Hendrik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.6/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
    from /home/Hendrik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.6/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:111:in `perform_request'
    from /home/Hendrik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/elasticsearch-api-1.0.6/lib/elasticsearch/api/namespace/common.rb:21:in `perform_request'
    from /home/Hendrik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/elasticsearch-api-1.0.6/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/indices/create.rb:77:in `create'
    from /home/Hendrik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/searchkick-2.5.0/lib/searchkick/index.rb:14:in `create'
    from /home/Hendrik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/searchkick-2.5.0/lib/searchkick/index.rb:184:in `create_index'
    from /home/Hendrik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/searchkick-2.5.0/lib/searchkick/index.rb:233:in `reindex_scope'
    from /home/Hendrik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/searchkick-2.5.0/lib/searchkick/model.rb:72:in `searchkick_reindex'
    from (irb):5
    from /home/Hendrik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/railties-4.1.16/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/Hendrik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/railties-4.1.16/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/Hendrik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/railties-4.1.16/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /home/Hendrik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/railties-4.1.16/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/Hendrik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/railties-4.1.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

It says I can change the values for max_gram, min_gram and max_ngram_diff in the level settings. But I have no Idea what level settings is or where I can find it.

Comment: I also encountered a similar situation and found a solution here
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57395902/trying-to-set-the-max-gram-and-min-gram-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're using an older version of Searchkick. Try upgrading to the latest version.

```sh
bundle update searchkick
```